# How can I get my delete messages function just appear for the user's own messages left on their friends page?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I had been working on this trying the delete message button to work on my own profile page of my site. When I delete a message left by a friend it not only deletes it from the screen but deletes it from the database. The messages in the database have 4 fields: message_id, from, to and message. Here is my profile view that shows how I am deleting messages from my friends:

```
       if(!empty($messages)){
       foreach($messages as $message):
       $delete = $message['message_id']; 
       //var_dump($message); ?>
      <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"(<?=anchor("home/deleteMsg/$delete", 'delete')?>)</li> //this is where the delete button appears beside messages left
     <?php endforeach?> 
      <?php }else{ ?>
     <?php echo 'No messages left yet !!!'; }?>
```

Here is my controller showing the deleteMsg function called:

```
function deleteMsg($messageid) 
         {

        $this->messages->deleteMsg($messageid);

        redirect('home');

         }
```

Here is the messages model showing the deleteMsg model itself:

```
 function deleteMsg($message_id)
      {

        $this->db->where(array('message_id' => $message_id));
        $this->db->delete('messages');

      }
```

Here is my friendprofile view where I want to implement the delete message command just so the button appears for messages Ive left and I can delete them. The delete button will not appear beside other friends comments on this page:

```
          <li><?=$message['from']?> says...: "<?=$message['message']?>"</li>
```

Now I've tried creating a new delete Message function to no success so far, am I better off doing this than calling the same function? As this didnt work either.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest enabling the CodeIgniter's profiling setting, this way you'll be able to see what queries have been run on your db, just paste the code bellow in your controller:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```